# How Can I Add a New Command to a Control's Event

Tags: wpf, mvvm

thanks for taking a look at this question.

I have been building an application (VB/WPF) following Josh Smith's example of an MVVM pattern: [Click here to view](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/InternationalizedWizard.aspx)

My Views have Controls which trigger a Command upon an event, such as a button click and these are bound to properties in the ViewModel.

My ViewModel exposes properties of type ICommand which invoke the appropriate methods.

This has worked well, until now! I now want to use a Thumb Control to allow a user to move an object within a Canvas. I don't believe that the Thumb has a Command capability 'out of the box'. A Thumb raises a 'DragDelta' event when being moved. So my question is as follows:

How do I extend a Control's capability to issue a Command upon an event please?

I wish to issue a new Command, let's say 'onDragDelta' so that I can bind it to a property in my ViewModel just like my Buttons.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

What you want is to fire an ICommand in your ViewModel based on a FrameworkElement's RoutedEvent. Unfortunately, WPF doesn't support this "out-of-box". Some possibilities:

1) With Expression Blend 3 there is Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.dll, which allows this. See [WPF : Blend 3 Interactions / Behaviours](http://sachabarber.net/?p=510) for an example on how to do this.

2) You could have an event handler in your code-behind, which directly calls the appropriate ViewModel command. For example:

```
private void FrameworkElement_DragDelta(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MyViewModel.OnDragDelta(sender, e);
}
```

3) As part of the [Cinch](http://cinch.codeplex.com/) framework, there is an [attached command behaviour](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CinchII.aspx#CommandAtt). That way, you do not have to change your code-behind. For example:

```
Cinch:SingleEventCommand.RoutedEventName="DragDelta"
Cinch:SingleEventCommand.TheCommandToRun="{Binding Path=DragDeltaCommand}"
```

Note that this calls an ICommand and passes an object (actually an SCommandArgs) as command parameter. To get the actual routed event arguments in your command handler, do the following:

```
var sargs = args as SCommandArgs;
if (sargs == null)
{
    return;
}

var routedEventArgs = sargs.EventArgs as RoutedEventArgs; // Or whatever arguments you actually expect
if (routedEventArgs == null)
{
    return;
}

// Do something here with the event arguments
```

EDIT: Also take a look at [Binding Commands to Events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939388/binding-commands-to-events)

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your advice.

I started by handling the Thumb's 'DragDelta' event in the code behind and bound the event's HorizontalChanged and VerticalChanged values to properties in my ViewModel. I then bound my Thumb's Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties to my ViewModel. Simple and neat but I felt the need to remove the code behind.

I think that HorizontalChanged and VerticalChanged are only available as arguments of the Thumb's DragDelta event. With this in mind I'm not sure how I could bind these directly to the ViewModel.

Comment: If you only get the data as part of the event's arguments, then you'll either have to use the approach (1) or (3), or have a small code-behind. BTW I don't think there is anything wrong with having some code-behind, as long as there is no major (difficult to test) logic involved.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an `ICommand`, I would rather *data bind* the Thumb's current position to a property in your ViewModel. Now, if the position is changed, you could execute some method in your ViewModel with the difference as parameter.

I do not know whether this fits your needs, but that was my first thought.