# Binding event handler with static property's sub property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

There is a static object SomeClass.Current in my app which has property MySelectionChangedEvent. In WPF I need to bind ListBox SelectionChanged event to this subproperty. For not-a-handler properties of the static object this binding works correctly, but not for the handler:

```
<ListBox SelectionChanged="{Binding Path=MySelectionChangedEvent, Source={x:Static SomeClass.Current}}" ...></ListBox>
```

, I tried to declare MySelectionChangedEvent in these ways:

```
public EventHandler<SelectionChangedEventArgs> MySelectionChangedEvent{get;set;}
```

or

```
public event EventHandler<SelectionChangedEventArgs> MySelectionChangedEvent;
```

or

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MySelectionChangedEventProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MySelectionChangedEvent", 
         typeof(EventHandler<SelectionChangedEventArgs>), 
         typeof(SomeClass), 
         new PropertyMetadata(new EventHandler<SelectionChangedEventArgs>((s, e) => { })));
```

But everything leads to runtime error:

`Cannot find DependencyProperty or PropertyInfo for property named 'MySelectionChangedEvent'. Property names are case sensitive.  Error at object 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBox' in markup file 'DbEditor;component/...'`

What is correct way to bind event handler to property(or field) of a static object?

Comment: have you tried EventSetter in the ListBox's Style?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430256/wpf-event-binding-to-viewmodel-for-non-command-classes

Comment: @Bizz, there is no word about static properties there, but the answer to that question is correct for me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved simply by calling my custom handler from standard generated method.