# PreviewMouseDown binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I started to use MVVM pattern in my app, I have `ListView` and I want to raplace:

```
<ListView>
     <ListViewItem PreviewMouseDown="Choose_PreviewMouseDown"/>
</ListView>
```

with something like:

```
<ListView>
     <ListViewItem PreviewMouseDown="{Binding PreviewMouseDownCommand}"/>
</ListView>
```

but it says: `'PreviewMouseDownCommand' is not a method`

> **Update**
>
> There is answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4897897/10705051)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Event Binding to ViewModel (for non-Command classes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430256/wpf-event-binding-to-viewmodel-for-non-command-classes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Binding UI events to commands in ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897775/wpf-binding-ui-events-to-commands-in-viewmodel)