# Highlight custom DataTemplate in TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, highlight

I have a simple `TreeView` that I'm trying to create a custom `DataTemplate` for.  It displays as desired, but when I attempt to select the `TreeViewItem`, the highlighting does not work if I click the text in the `TreeView`.  However, if I select just to the left of the text, it works:

[image: TreeView selection issue]

The source is pretty straight forward, so I'm guessing I'm just missing a styling connection:

xaml

```
   <TreeView x:Name="treeView"
             ItemsSource="{Binding TreeViewItems}"
             Grid.Row="0">
      <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
         <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}">
            <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Header}">
               <TreeViewItem.InputBindings>
                  <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick"
                                Command="{Binding Command}" />
               </TreeViewItem.InputBindings>
            </TreeViewItem>
         </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
   </TreeView>
```

I've tried adding this to the xaml, but it didnt help:

```
      <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" 
                BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}" />
      </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

TreeViewModel

```
   public class TreeViewModel : BaseNotifyModel, ITreeViewModel
   {
      public TreeViewModel(ITreeViewService menuService)
      {
         TreeViewItems = 
            new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel>(menuService.TreeViewMenu);
      }

      public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel> TreeViewItems
      {
         get
         {
            return Get<ReadOnlyObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel>>();
         }
         private set
         {
            Set(value);
         }
      }
   }
```

MenuItemViewModel

```
  public class MenuItemViewModel : BaseNotifyModel
   {
      public MenuItemViewModel()
      {
         MenuItems = 
            new ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel>();
      }

      public String Header
      {
         get
         {
            return Get<String>();
         }
         set
         {
            Set(value);
         }
      }

      public ICommand Command
      {
         get
         {
            return Get<ICommand>();
         }
         set
         {
            Set(value);
         }
      }

      public ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel> MenuItems
      {
         get
         {
            return Get<ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel>>();
         }
         set
         {
            Set(value);
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Why are you putting a TreeViewItem in a data template for a TreeViewItem? Why do you want two nested tree view items?

Comment: Just put regular TextBlock in template, not another TreeViewItem.

Comment: I'd do the input bindings in the ItemContainerStyle, and bind Header to MenuItemViewModel.Header in the style as well, and just toss a `<ContentControl Content="{Binding Header}" />` in the data template. Or just use a TextBlock or Label as Evk says.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, seems warranted

Comment: @EdPlunkett - I want to add a custom command action to it

Comment: @Evk - Doesnt fix the issue

Comment: @SwDevMan81 Put InputBindings on the TextBlock, Label, or whatever you're using to display the item content. That's the visible element; the user will click on it.

Comment: Upvoted for justice :) Question is formulated good to my mind. As for the question: why don't bind to SelectedItem or use SelectedItemChanged event of treeview? Your click handler "eats" click so it does not get delivered futher up the tree. If you used regular event (like LeftMouseButtonUp etc) - you could let it propagate futher, but in this case not sure how to do that.

Comment: @EdPlunkett - I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  I want to put the InputBindings on the TreeViewItem (I'd rather not do this in code behind, but rather in the xaml)

Comment: @SwDevMan81 You already have a TreeViewItem. That's what you're templating. If the templated content fills the treeview item, why do you care if in some arcane sense the user is clicking on its contents rather than the treeview item itself? It's the same clickable area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from @Ed Plunket and @Evk, I found a solution that will work. I switched to a `ContentPresenter` and used the `Interaction.Triggers` to call the command on the `MouseLeftButtonUp` action.

```
   <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TreeViewItems}">
      <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
         <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Header}">
               <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                  <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                     <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.Command, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}" />
                  </i:EventTrigger>
               </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </ContentPresenter>
         </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
   </TreeView>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `TreeView` is creating a `TreeViewItem` for each item in `ItemsSource`, so don't nest another `TreeViewItem` inside the one that the `TreeView` already created for you. That doesn't serve any purpose. Your template should just be providing a way for the existing `TreeViewItem` to display whatever's in its `DataContext` (your `MenuItemViewModel`, in this case).

You want to display the `Header` property in the tree view item; so just do that. Nothing fancy, just a `Label` or `ContentControl`, or even a `TextBlock` if it's `String` (though it's a lot of fun in WPF to have the flexibility of arbitrary content). When the user clicks on the content, your command executes. The only thing the user can see in the tree is the content. That's the only visible part of the `TreeViewItem` item, so that's what the user is going to click on.

Problem number two: Once the input binding is getting `LeftClick`, that breaks selection in the `TreeView`. It appears to me that you can't get there from here by that method.

```
  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
     <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}">
        <ContentControl 
            Content="{Binding Header}"
            Background="Transparent"
            >
           <ContentControl.InputBindings>
              <!-- This invokes the command, but breaks selection -->
              <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick"
                            Command="{Binding Command}" />
           </ContentControl.InputBindings>
        </ContentControl>
     </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

Here's what you can do:

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}">
        <ContentControl 
            Content="{Binding Header}"
            Background="Transparent"
            >
        </ContentControl>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
        <EventSetter Event="Selected" Handler="MenuTreeViewItem_Click" />
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Codebehind

```
private void MenuTreeViewItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((MenuItemViewModel)((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext).Command.Execute(null);
}
```

[There *is* a way to bind an event to a command in pure XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/959895/424129), but it requires some C# code (LOL). But I mean, it's "pure XAML" in the sense that it's a nice generalized reusable attached behavior, not an unsightly event handler in your codebehind. Instead, it does exactly what I did above, but it does it in code that you can more easily avert your eyes from, and that you can reuse in pure XAML.

Comment: Ok, I see now.  However when I try this, the command works when clicking on the text, but it does not highlight the text (Unless I double click).

Comment: @SwDevMan81 Updated. Explicitly set `Background` to `Transparent`. Changing the `ContentControl` to a `Label` will work too; that has a `Transparent` background by default. The only catch is that if your command is doing something that interferes with keyboard focus, that'll break the selection highlighting regardless. E.g., my test code command originally popped up a MessageBox, which prevented the selection from happening. I think it stole focus before the TreeView knew what was happening, so there was never a selection.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, setting Background doesn't really help. Click event is still eaten by LeftClick handler and so item is not highlighted.

Comment: Note that I'm not OP :) Also trying to help him. Sure I myself won't do it this way, but still interesting case. I use template from question with your ItemTemplate. So just TreeView with ItemTemplate, nothing else. LeftClick Command writes one line to trace, nothing else. And still when you click on item in tree view, sometimes (very often) it won't be selected (but LeftClick handler will be executed). BUT if I replace LeftClick with regular MouseLeftButtonUp event - everything works fine.

Comment: @Evk Whoops! Sorry! :)

Comment: @Evk OK, I screwed up. You're right, the input binding is in fact interfering with selection. OP's best option is to handle the `Selected` event and call `((MenuItemViewModel)((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext).Command.Invoke()`

Comment: @Evk Updated answer. Not what OP really wants to hear, but this time it *does* actually work.

Comment: Thanks everyone, if there is a fundamentally different approach for this, I'm fine with that too.  Otherwise this might just be what I do.