# Binding Button Click Event to a Method in ViewModel with Interaction.Triggers when Buttons are dynamically created at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

In my C# WPF MVVM pattern application, I have an ItemsControl in my View that draws Lines and Buttons on a Canvas based on a bound ItemsSource, defined in XAML as below:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewmodels:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

.
.
.

<ItemsControl
    x:Name="DiagramViewCanvas"
    ItemsSource="{Binding DiagramObjects, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LineObject}">
            <Line
                X1="{Binding XStart}"
                Y1="{Binding YStart}"
                X2="{Binding XEnd}"
                Y2="{Binding YEnd}"
                Stroke="White"
                StrokeThickness="1"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ButtonObject}">
            <Button
                Style="{DynamicResource MyDiagramButtonStyle}"
                Width="225"
                Height="30"
                Content="{Binding Content}"
                FontSize="13"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Background="Black" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding XPosition, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding YPosition, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

</ItemsControl>
```

**This code works completely fine**. My question is how to bind the Buttons' Click event to a method in the ViewModel (MainWindowViewModel).

**Option 1** (which I don't want to use due MVVM pattern): If I try a simple Click event definition as below ...

```
<Button
    Style="{DynamicResource MyDiagramButtonStyle}"
    Width="225"
    Height="30"
    Content="{Binding Content}"
    FontSize="13"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
    Click="OnButtonClick"/>
```

... where OnButtonClick is defined in my XAML codebehind, **the OnButtonClick method is successfully called and executed for each Button that is created at runtime. It works fine**.

**Option 2:** However, if I try to use Interaction.Triggers as below (which is the approach I regularly use without any problems in my code) to avoid placing code in code behind ...

```
<Button
    Style="{DynamicResource MyDiagramButtonStyle}"
    Width="225"
    Height="30"
    Content="{Binding Content}"
    FontSize="13"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <i:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="OnButtonClick"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

... where OnButtonClick is defined in my MainWindowViewModel ...

```
public void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Button btn)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

... **I get the following error:**

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Could not find method named 'OnButtonClick' on object of type 'ButtonObject' that matches the expected signature.'
```

**Question 1:** Am I making a basic mistake in my implementation of interaction triggers (I have many other interaction triggers in my code that work completely fine)? Or is it that Interaction.Triggers do not work in this scenario where the Buttons are created dynamically at runtime?

**Question 2:** Should I be using ICommand instead (for example as mentioned in [Binding Commands to Events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939388/binding-commands-to-events))?

Thanks for any direction on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: "I would like the method OnButtonClick to reside in my ViewModel" so you basically want to throw away all principles of mvvm. wpf will figth you every step, good luck

Comment: Forget about click event handlers and triggers. Just include an `ICommand` item in your `ButtonObject` class and bind directly to that.

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution using Interaction.Triggers:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
        <i:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}, Path=DataContext}" MethodName="OnButtonClick"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```